# How to build an effective trade route?

Tags: port-royale-3

In Port Royale 3, how can I earn much money by setting up an effective trade route?

Is there a certain combination of cities that is especially profitable?

Should you rather create smaller roundtrips between a few cities or long routes?

What other tips are there for trade routes that can help beginners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick any set of cities to go to, but I prefer Port Royale - Santiago - Port au Prince, but that's just me.

Be sure to set the trade route preference to "Profit".

If you want to gain a lot of money but time is not a matter to you, go for long routes.
If you want to gain a bit less money but time is a matter, go for short routes.

There isn't a lot for tips.

**In the later stages, trade routes will give you more loss than profit.**